# HTML5 Drag'n'Drop - Not Working on iOS 12.1.2 (Safari and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, drag-and-drop, webkit

## Background

I have a list that is sortable via drag and drop. It works perfectly on desktop browser, and on Chrome on Android. However, it didn't work at all on Safari and Chrome on iOS 12.1.2 (iPhone 8).

## Current Code

See snippet below, and also for easy mobile testing: https://codepen.io/Kelderic/pen/KJMRgb

```js
var dragging = null;

document.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
  var target = getLI(event.target);
  dragging = target;
  event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', null);
  event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(self.dragging, 0, 0);
});

document.addEventListener('dragover', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = getLI(event.target);
  var bounding = target.getBoundingClientRect()
  var offset = bounding.y + (bounding.height / 2);
  if (event.clientY - offset > 0) {
    target.style['border-bottom'] = 'solid 4px blue';
    target.style['border-top'] = '';
  } else {
    target.style['border-top'] = 'solid 4px blue';
    target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
  }
});

document.addEventListener('dragleave', function(event) {
  var target = getLI(event.target);
  target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
  target.style['border-top'] = '';
});

document.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = getLI(event.target);
  if (target.style['border-bottom'] !== '') {
    target.style['border-bottom'] = '';
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(dragging, event.target.nextSibling);
  } else {
    target.style['border-top'] = '';
    target.parentNode.insertBefore(dragging, event.target);
  }
});

function getLI(target) {
  while (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'li' && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'body') {
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
  if (target.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'body') {
    return false;
  } else {
    return target;
  }
}
```

```css
ul.sorting {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

ul.sorting li {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: move;
}

ul.sorting li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sorting">
  <li draggable="true" style="user-drag:element;">List Item 15</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 2</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 3</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 4</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 5</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 6</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 7</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 8</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 9</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 10</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 11</li>
  <li draggable="true" style="-webkit-user-drag:element;">List Item 12</li>
</ul>
```

## Video of Behavior on iOS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDyXF.jpg (Size is too large for direct embed)

## Question

Why is this not working on iOS? I can't even get the `dragstart` event to fire. On Android Chrome, a longpress fires the `dragstart`.

My fallback idea is to make a longpress using `touchstart` and `touchend`, then create my own absolutely positioned ghost element and drag it around manually. That is a lot of extra code when the `drag*` events should just work.

Am I missing something?

## Edit

LI elements in mobile Safari have an `ondragstart` event as part of their prototype. The question is getting it to fire.

Also, according to caniuse, mobile Safari should support this. However, caniuse also shows Android Chrome as not supporting, which isn't true.

Comment: Maybe it's the old sad story that it works only on iPad and not on iPhone? Did you try iPad?

Comment: For what it's worth, the codepen example doesn't work for me on Chrome 71.0.3578.98, on Mac OS X 10.14.2, but does work on Firefox. Dragging on Chrome seems to have no effect, though the DOM gets very subtly changed - the style attribute of the <li> element gets a space character added between "-webkit-user-drag:" and "element;".

Comment: Oops. I was playing around with it today and forgot that the pen was linked here. I need to restore the behavior from the question posting time.

Comment: @Rob, I fixed the CodePen example to be the code here. What you say a few minutes ago was a WIP version that was broken in Chrome due to DOM manipulation in the `dragstart` event.

Comment: @Olafant, I have not tested iPad. I don't have access to one, unfortunately.

Comment: Just tested on ios 15.2.1 and this drag and drop functionality is working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have done a lot of research over the past week on this topic, and I've done a lot of testing and debugging. What I have discovered is that **iOS supports drag events, but iOS doesn't trigger them.** (As of iOS 12)

If you test webpage on iOS Safari, you'll see that all HTML elements have `ondragstart` attached to their prototype. The drag events are all there. They just never get triggered.

Others have run into this issue as well. Event Modernizer [doesn't detect Drag and Drop support](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/637) because of this false support.

Additionally, I dug through the Safari docs, and [found this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW19):

> iOS Note: Although drag and drop are not supported, you can produce...

It says "supported", but immediately below, there is an event table, which shows `drag` and says that it isn't "Generated".

This means that [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop) is currently wrong, and needs updated.

---

## Direct Answer To Question

The code is not working solely because Apple has chosen not to ***trigger*** drag events.

Comment: @Bharata, the reason I didn't award you the bounty was that you didn't really answer the question. Saying that I have to use touch events doesn't explain why drag events aren't working. Safari does technically support the events, because they are part of element prototypes. It just doesn't fire those events. Your answer didn't really address the drag events at all. There was no research, and you admitted you couldn't even test appreciate the response. I appreciate the response, but it wasn't the answer.

Comment: I found this still isn't working with iOS 13.3 (Jan. 2020), but it still says it is supported on caniuse.com...

Comment: interestingly, I opened the codepen attached to the question, converted the page to mimic Galaxy S5 device and the DnD feature was not working but when the codepen is opened from android mobile, it is working.

Comment: @AndyMercer You didn't propose the solution but the problem as an answer :(

Answer (score 6):

I forked your codepen test case here: https://codepen.io/bobacus/pen/MLjZMg

I was wondering if the listeners needed to be added to the `<li>` elements, so changed some of the code:

```
listEl = document.getElementById('my_list');
for (var i = 0; i < listEl.children.length; i ++) {
    itemEl = listEl.children[i];
    itemEl.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
      dragging = getLI(event.target);
      if (dragging) {
          event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', null);
          event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(dragging, 0, 0);
      }
    });
}
```

But that didn't work.

I tried a few different things, but what finally got it to work in Safari was adding a polyfill described here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1091766/Add-support-for-standard-HTML-Drag-and-Drop-operat

I added this to the top of the HTML snippet:

```
<script src="http://bernardo-castilho.github.io/DragDropTouch/DragDropTouch.js"></script>
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: The `dragstart` event bubbles, so it shouldn't matter if it is attached to the `li` elements or the wrapper. I've tried out a couple polyfills, but my goal was to avoid using any. There isn't an option, unfortunately, because of the way iOS has disabled the drag events.

Comment: Polyfill code worked great for me, and got standard HTML5 draggable to work as expected

Comment: Saved me with the polyfill. Thanks @Rob!

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I do not have a device with iOS12 (my device does not suppot it) and I can not test it. And I do not know why iOS/Apple support writes that they support this events in iOS 11.2 and on your new device it is not supported.

**Alternative workaround**

With this workaround you will get a solution for all modern devices and browsers. It is better than to wait for support from iOS/Apple.

`dragstart`, `dragover`, `dragleave`, `drop` events do not work on **all** touch devices.

You have to use the apropriate event names for your touch events like:

- `touchstart`
- `touchend`
- `touchcancel`
- `touchmove`

Read **[the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)** about this events.

> In order to provide quality support for touch-based user interfaces, touch events offer the ability to interpret finger (or stylus) activity on touch screens or trackpads.
>
> The touch events interfaces are relatively low-level APIs that can be used to support application specific multi-touch interactions such as a two-finger gesture. A multi-touch interaction starts when a finger (or stylus) first touches the contact surface. Other fingers may subsequently touch the surface and optionally move across the touch surface. The interaction ends when the fingers are removed from the surface. During this interaction, an application receives touch events during the start, move and end phases.
>
> Touch events are similar to mouse events except they support simultaneous touches and at different locations on the touch surface. The TouchEvent interface encapsulates all of the touch points that are currently active. The Touch interface, which represents a single touch point, includes information such as the position of the touch point relative to the browser viewport.

Unfortunatelly, the events `touchenter` and `touchleave` were deleted from the specification and because of this if you need it then you have to write a workaround using `document.elementFromPoint()` like follows:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e)
{
    var touch = e.touches[0],
        elementFromPoint = document.elementFromPoint(touch.pageX - window.pageXOffset, touch.pageY - window.pageYOffset);

    if(elem == elementFromPoint) //elem is your element which was entered
    {
        //your code for touchenter event
    }
    else //the code for touchleave event
});
```

Maybe for some other mobile devices and their browsers you will need to use polyfills (**[1](https://github.com/Bernardo-Castilho/dragdroptouch)**, **[2](https://github.com/timruffles/mobile-drag-drop)**) which enable HTML5 drag drop support on mobile (touch) devices.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the answer! You are incorrect on a couple points, though. As I said in my question, the drag and drop code works perfectly on touch devices Android. A long press triggers the drag behavior. It's only iOS that it isn't working. Second, support was officially added to iOS in iOS 11.2, so it should work there as well, without having to use touch events.

Comment: @AndyMercer, hi! They could write something, but would you like to write a solution for all devices or maybe you want it only for your device? If you really want it only for your device then I am wrong, but in other case – not, because without it you will not get it on all devices. Unfortunately I do not have a device with iOS12 (my device does not suppot it) and I can not test it. You can also try to read the article **["Native HTML5 Drag and Drop"](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)**.

Comment: Again, I appreciate the response. However, given that I've written the code in my question, I clearly understand the HTML Drag and Drop API, so reading articles about it won't help. My question is very specific. I have code which works on all desktop browsers, works on mobile Android, and doesn't work on mobile iOS. It should, according to what I've found online, work on mobile iOS. So the question is, why is it not working there. See https://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop. It lists mobile iOS starting from 11 as supporting this.